# Should it be "I went to hot springs", "I went to a hot spring", or "I went to the hot springs"?

Tags: articles

What's the correct alternative?

For example, you're visiting a new city and you wanna check out a place where they have hot springs. But you're not mentioning the name of the place to the person you're talking to.

Example sentence:

> Mary went to __ with her girlfriends.

If all of them are correct, what are their difference?

Comment: All three are acceptable, depending on what you intend to say.

Comment: @CowperKettle The general way of saying it. For example, you're visiting a new city and you wanna check out a place where they have hot springs. But you're not mentioning the name of the place to the person you're talking to.

Comment: Just jumping in for CowperKettle. Mary went to a hot spring with her girlfriends (the city has more than one). Mary went to the hot springs with her girlfriends (the city has just the one). And I personally would not say, "Mary went to hot springs." Unfortunately, you'll have to wait for her to help us understand this option better.

Comment: "Mary went to hot springs wherever she found them."